# Spring @Controller, Validator and JSF <h:messages /> tag

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC `@Controller` (with a Spring `Validator`) and a  JSF page.

What I want is to show **validation errors** in the JSF page using the JSF `<h:messages />` tag.

As far as I know:

- `MessageContext`  + `MessageBuilder` works for webflows but it is not available for `@Controller`
- I've read the Spring documentation about [Validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) and it seems (last paragraph) the only way is using Spring MVC tags.

¿Is there a way to show errors with `<h:messages />` from my `@Controller` `Validator` without using Spring MVC tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fooling around with Spring and JSF messages integration, finally i found the easiest way was:

- Add faces messages directly in the application controller (though @M. Deinum shows an architectural solution)
- Use jsf validators instead of spring validators, still being possible to access the spring context

That works and i think it's a clean integration.

Answer (score 1):

Not by default there isn't.

What you could do is create a `HandlerInterceptor` which implements the `postHandle` method (I assume you use normal Spring MVC things for everything). In this method you could lookup all model attributes of the type `BindingResult`, retrieve all the errors from it and transfer them to JSF.

Something like this should work (haven't tested it and depends on what you use furthermore)

```
public class ErrorTransferingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter implements MessageSourceAware {

    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        for (Object o : modelAndView.getModel().values() ) {
            if (o instanceof Errors) {
                Errors result = (Errors) o;
                for (ObjectError err : result.getAllErrors() ) {
                    String msg = messageSource.getMessage(err, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
                    if (err instanceof FieldError) {
                        ctx.addMessage(((FieldError) err).getField(), new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, null));
                    } else {
                        ctx.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, null));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource=messageSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Deinum. Just 1 problem. The FacesContext is `null` at this point. As I've seen, handlers are executed (`DispatcherServlet`) before actually creating the FacesContext at the Spring JsfView. We are close to find a solution... ;)

Comment: A shoot, you are right. But you are using `JsfView` which also means you are using Spring Web Flow. Instead of the interceptor use a custom `ViewFactory` which returns a custom `JsfView` which puts the messages in the `FacesContext`. The current `JsfView` doesn't do that.